# API Integration Service

Tags: api, authorization, integration

We want to integrate into many different APIs so that our users can import their data on other apps into our app or do actions on their other apps when triggered on our app.
Plain API integration.

However, integration process takes too long for many services and you have to fill lots of forms. You have to submit a request to that platform, they check it, then publish in a few weeks or months. Doing this with many different apps can take months.

I just want to delegate the authorization process to another service. For example, https://auth0.com/ can authenticate users on their platform. This way, you can just use Auth0 and users can sign up to your app from hundreds of different apps. I need something similar to that but I need the access token.

Whenever a user wants to integrate another app to our app, I will redirect the user to that intermediary service and it will handle authorization and return us the access token.

Is there a service that can do that? Is this allowed by services like Google or Microsoft?

Answer (score 4):

One platform I found is apideck.com
Handles authorization process instead of you, your users can see which apps they integrated over their panel or widget.
Allows you to quickly connect to tens of api services.